AC compressor receives power but doesn't engage
I have a 2012 Nissan Rogue. The AC stopped working. When the AC is on full blast the AC compressor doesn't spin. When the car is powered off the clutch on the compressor spins freely. I pulled out the power plug on top of the compressor. I cranked the car and put the AC on full blast. My multimeter showed that power was indeed being sent to the compressor. Does that rule out all other factors such as pressure sensors, relays, charge, etc.?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If what you're saying is accurate, I'd suggest the clutch is bad on your AC compressor. If it's getting power and not engaging, that pretty much leaves everything else out. One thing you can do is to use a 12v battery and apply power directly to the clutch. It should be easily seen as engaging if it is working as it should. This eliminate that there is a connection issue between the plug and the clutch. This is just a "sanity check" if you'd like to do it.

Excellent first step. Kevin, if still unsure after that, release tension on the serp belt, engage the AC clutch as suggested and see if the pulley feels connected to the compressor shaft. If not, it's a worn out clutch for sure.

@MTA - I guess you're suggesting the clutch friction material may be worn out? If so, spot on add.

Exactly. If he hears a loud click but the pulley still spins freely or just drags a little but does not effectively turn the compressor shaft, then the AC clutch is shot even though it's working electrically.

Thanks to both of you for the sanity checks and extra things to make sure I'm on the right track.
